# Error message: ValueError: too many values to unpack in Frequecy distribution of NLTK

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I am getting error as ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) for the below code. I am not sure whether it is because of too many nouns count.

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
import nltk

tagged_words = brown.tagged_words(categories='mystery')

for word, tag in tagged_words:
   if any(noun_tag in tag for noun_tag in ['NP', 'NN']):

       nouns=(word,tag)


for word, tag in nouns:
   nouns_freq =nltk.FreqDist(word)
```

Please suggest

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\\Word2Vec.py", line 12, in module


for word, tag in nouns:

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Where exactly? Please update your question with the full error trace.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\kaushikchoudhury\Downloads\PYTHON\Own Program\NLP\Word2Vec.py", line 28, in <module>
    nouns_freq = nltk.FreqDist([word for word, tag in nouns])
  File "C:\Users\kaushikchoudhury\Downloads\PYTHON\Own Program\NLP\Word2Vec.py", line 28, in <listcomp>
    nouns_freq = nltk.FreqDist([word for word, tag in nouns])
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Please do **not** post code or error messages as comments - they are literally unreadable! As already said, *edit & update* your question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question with error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will give you the frequency of nouns of the mystery genre in brown corpus.

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
from nltk import FreqDist

tagged_words = brown.tagged_words(categories='mystery')

# get list of lowercased nouns    
nouns = [word[0].lower() for word in tagged_words if word[1] in ['NP', 'NN']]    
nouns_freq = FreqDist(nouns)
```